# Can't to Drop a column name(2021.0)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Want to drop this col

```
 df3 = df2.drop(labels="2021.0", axis=1)
```

Error I get

```
   KeyError: "['2021.0'] not found in axis"
```

---

Also done that

```
  df3=df2.drop(["2021.0"], axis='columns')
```

But also get same error

[image: dataset]

Comment: '2021.0' not available simple it can not show in picture you share.

Comment: Note that column names don't have to be strings.

df2.drop(columns=[2021]) could work.

Comment: `df3=df2.drop(['2021.0'], axis=1)` hope it can help

Comment: sometime jupyter kernal also make an issue after a long run so restart your kernal too.

Answer (score 0):

Try without quotes;

```
df3 = df2.drop(labels=2021.0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the column name is not of type String. If you remove the quotes it should work.

```
df3 = df2.drop(labels=2021.0, axis=1)
```

or alternatively just

```
df3 = df2.drop(2021.0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Not working. Same error

Comment: In a new cell, run ```df2.columns```. Does 2021.0 show up? If it does, what type is it?

Comment: Also, is it a case that the column is already deleted. I have this problem with Jupyter Notebook sometimes where running a cell once does the job, but running it again throws an error. Sometimes, if you can, it is always good to ```Run all``` cells again